# Check style name or get style name VSTO Word VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto, word-style

I wrote the following code in Word VBA and it works.

```
Dim para As Paragraph
Dim nextPara As Paragraph
For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If para.Style = CMB1.Value Then
        Set nextPara = para.Next
        If nextPara.Style = CMB2.Value Then
            If Not nextPara Is Nothing Then
                para.Style = CMB3.Value
                nextPara.Style = CMB4.Value
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I converted that code to VSTO VB.NET:

```
    Dim para As Word.Paragraph
    Dim nextPara As Word.Paragraph

    For Each para In activeDoc.Paragraphs
        If para.Style = cmbStyle1.SelectedItem.ToString Then
            nextPara = para.Next
            If nextPara.Style = cmbStyle2.SelectedItem.ToString Then
                If Not nextPara Is Nothing Then
                    para.Style = cmbStyle3.SelectedItem.ToString
                    nextPara.Style = cmbStyle4.SelectedItem.ToString
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

But when I run, in the following line, it gives an error.

> If Para.Style = cmbStyle1.SelectedItem.ToString Then

What should I do?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error message or exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with the Word PIAs can differ, sometimes, from VBA. Not a lot when you work with VB.NET, but sometimes a bit...

In order to get the style's name you first need a Style object. For example

```
    Dim para As Word.Paragraph = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range.Paragraphs(1)
    Dim styl As Word.Style = para.Range.Style
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(styl.NameLocal)
```

So your code would need to be something like the code that follows. Note that it's not necessary to create a Style object in order to *assign* a style to a Range. Only when getting the style's properties.

```
Dim para As Word.Paragraph
Dim nextPara As Word.Paragraph
Dim paraStyle as Word.Style
Dim paraStyleNext as Word.Style

For Each para In activeDoc.Paragraphs
    paraStyle = para.Style
    If paraStyle.NameLocal = cmbStyle1.SelectedItem.ToString Then
        nextPara = para.Next
        paraStyleNext = nextPara.Style
        If paraStyleNext.NameLocal = cmbStyle2.SelectedItem.ToString Then
            If Not nextPara Is Nothing Then
                para.Style = cmbStyle3.SelectedItem.ToString
                nextPara.Style = cmbStyle4.SelectedItem.ToString
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Paragraph.Style`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/paragraph-style-property-word) Property in Word is a Variant of the [`WdBuiltinStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdbuiltinstyle?view=word-pia) type. You'll have to reference the string [`Paragraph.Style.NameLocal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/style-namelocal-property-word).

Example:

```
If para.Style.NameLocal = cmbStyle1.SelectedItem.ToString Then
```

> Be sure to include error trapping in all your procedures. [Here is an example for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement)

Comment: I do it. but "para.Style.ToString" return "system._comobject" value.

Comment: `NameLocal` property is not available in the property list.